# how to read a csv file which have comma in between the values in Informatica or talend tools?

Tags: etl, talend, informatica-powercenter

I have an input file where I have values like "Bengaluru","New,Delhi","New,York" and I want to read this data as `Bengaluru,New Delhi,New York` : commas inside the double quotes should not be evaluated as a separator :  "New,Delhi" is evaluated as "New Delhi" and not separated in two items ("New" and "Delhi")

Answer (score 2):

In Informatica you can specify the text qualifier as double quotes in source definition. That would give you the expected values.

Comment: Yup Samik, It is working in Informatica but in talend still i need to check.